# Задать настройки на первом листе

Tags: excel

Мне надо, чтобы все, что я делаю с  первым листом, автоматически менялось бы и на остальных 14-ти. Для чайников много что перечитала, но не понимаю, как же тут делать.

Чтобы добиться такого результата (показываю, какой нужен результат) – после коррекции, фото ниже:

[image]

Я делаю такие действия:

1) Меняю стиль, хоть он внесен, но нормальный BarCode не формируется автоматом, поэтому провожу такие действия:

[image]

2) Растягию расстояние между двумя этикетками, мне надо это расстояние соблюсти:

[image]

3) Настройки печати листа А4:

[image]

Comment: Возможно, не нужно 14 листов, достаточно одного?
Шаблон с этикеткам на одном листе, данные на другом.
Или основная задача в другом?

Comment: Нужно все 14 листов, т.к. это этикетки на коробки. Я хочу поменять первый лист и чтоб автоматом поменялись все оставшиеся 13 листов, т.к. очень много надо играться с каждым. Но, к сожалению, моего ума не хватает этого сделать.
Эти этикетки делает программа, и мне потом надо их корректировать - каждый листик в документе, будь то 5 листов или 14.

Comment: Программа не моя делает, а из портала формирует мои вводимые данные и дает сохранить EXCEL-файл, который в последствии мне надо кажный в документе листик корректировать. (Сюда поместила файл  http://files.webfile.ru/2999564b13e6cf26bd33853c0f3be060  )

Спасибо.

Comment: >>Нужно все 14 листов т.к. это этикетки на коробки
При нормальной автоматизации достаточно одного листа-шаблона.
Изменяемые данные каждой этикетки последовательно вставляются в шаблон и лист печатается. Так можно не 14 - сотни этикеток печатать.

Comment: Если делать шаблон, то мне придется вставлять каждый листик, т.к. там на этикетках разная информация и BarCode. А это получится такая же двойная работа, если бы я каждую этикетку корректировала. 

Я ярлык выделила, но когда выделяю последнего листа ярлык, то первый перестает быть выделенным, а если и еще пытаться после пометки корректировать, то все помеченное исчезает.

Очень извеняюсь, но не делая шаблон, а имея мой файл, вы можете сделать только для первого листа печать на 1 листе и на одном листе и портрет, и чтоб эти изменения деиствовали на последующие в документе листы?

Спасибо.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я всетаки не так делала поэтому у меня не получалось. теперь получилось и хочу поделиться если вдруг кому понадобиться.

в картинках описание поочередное.

http://keep4u.ru/full/5502219e23593e113486ea6b5aa91ff0.html

http://keep4u.ru/full/a4b389677d748846a9f94f357026e72c.html

http://keep4u.ru/full/6cd46b04a4eab27aa3fbd6a0feff32e3.html

http://keep4u.ru/full/82ed2c041277ca1330ffab1f58b29eef.html

Огромнейшее спасибо за помощь . !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделить ярлык первого листа, нажать *Shift*, выделить ярлык последнего листа - выделится диапазон листов. Произвести нужные изменения. Изменения коснутся всех листов.

Но "оптом" работают не все действия.